# How to create extension which adds REPL window to Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sdk, read-eval-print-loop, visual-studio-extensions

I need to develop extension which is adding new REPL(Read-Eval-Print-Loop) Window to VS2012. It must work similar to the "F#" window. I have never wrote any plugin for VS and was surprised to realize that there is almost no information about plugin development, only some small samples for VS2010.

Could you give me an advice where I could find simple example of source code for adding REPL window extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no simple example anywhere for this. What you might want to look at is the [Python Tools for Visual Studio's REPL window implementation](http://pytools.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Common/Product/ReplWindow/Repl/ReplWindow.cs), which is open source.